# Keyboard input and score. Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have found a "flappy game" project and I am modifying it to my liking.

I would like to know how I can control the definition "tap" with the keyboard and not with the mouse (I have tried the online code "onkey" and it did not work) and I would like to know if I can add a score.

Next I attach the code that I have in possession at the moment and I would appreciate some feedback.

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
from freegames import vector

bird = vector(0, 0)
balls = []

def tap(x, y):
    "Move bird up in response to screen tap."
    up = vector(0, 30)
    bird.move(up)

def inside(point):
    "Return True if point on screen."
    return -200 < point.x < 200 and -200 < point.y < 200

def draw(alive):
    "Draw screen objects."
    clear()

    goto(bird.x, bird.y)

    if alive:
        dot(10, 'green')
    else:
        dot(10, 'red')

    for ball in balls:
        goto(ball.x, ball.y)
        dot(20, 'black')

    update()

def move():
    "Update object positions."
    bird.y -= 5

    for ball in balls:
        ball.x -= 3

    if randrange(10) == 0:
        y = randrange(-199, 199)
        ball = vector(199, y)
        balls.append(ball)

    while len(balls) > 0 and not inside(balls[0]):
        balls.pop(0)

    if not inside(bird):
        draw(False)
        return

    for ball in balls:
        if abs(ball - bird) < 15:
            draw(False)
            return

    draw(True)
    ontimer(move, 50)

setup(420, 420, 370, 0)
hideturtle()
up()
tracer(False)
onscreenclick(tap)
move()
done()
```

I've tried all kinds of functions and none has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how I can control the definition "tap" with the
>   keyboard and not with the mouse

That should be as simple as replacing:

```
onscreenclick(tap)
```

with

```
onkey(tap, "Up")
listen()
```

and dropping the `x` and `y` arguments to `tap()`.  I've reworked your code below to make this change as well as eliminate:

```
from freegames import vector
```

and make it run just with what's available in turtle.  I also changed the logic of keeping vectors and having the default turtle draw dots in their locations to instead making the balls and bird all turtles and just moving them as needed.  Since turtles aren't garbage collected normally, I keep a list of balls that have gone off screen to reuse again:

```
from random import randrange
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

BIRD_RADIUS = 10
BALL_RADIUS = 20
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 420, 420
GALLERY_WIDTH, GALLERY_HEIGHT = WINDOW_WIDTH - BALL_RADIUS, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BIRD_RADIUS

def click():
    "Move bird up in response to screen key click."

    bird.forward(min(BIRD_RADIUS * 3, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - bird.ycor()))  # flying higher

def is_ball_inside(turtle):
    "Return True if point on screen."

    x = turtle.xcor()

    return -GALLERY_WIDTH/2 < x

def is_bird_inside(turtle):
    "Return True if point on screen."

    y = turtle.ycor()

    return -GALLERY_HEIGHT/2 < y < GALLERY_HEIGHT/2

def draw(is_alive):
    "Draw screen objects."

    if not is_alive:
        bird.color('red')

    screen.update()

def move():
    "Update object positions."

    if not is_bird_inside(bird):
        draw(False)  # flew or fell out of gallery
        return

    bird.backward(BIRD_RADIUS/2)  # falling to earth

    for ball in balls:
        ball.forward(3)

    for ball in balls:
        if ball.distance(bird) < (BIRD_RADIUS + BALL_RADIUS) / 2:
            draw(False)
            return

    while balls and not is_ball_inside(balls[0]):
        ball = balls.pop(0)
        ball.hideturtle()

        spare_balls.append(ball)  # reduce, reuse, recycle

    if randrange(10) == 0:
        ball = spare_balls.pop() if spare_balls else Turtle("circle", visible=False)
        ball.shapesize(BALL_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
        ball.setheading(180)
        ball.penup()
        ball.goto(GALLERY_WIDTH/2, randrange(BALL_RADIUS - GALLERY_HEIGHT/2, GALLERY_HEIGHT/2 - BALL_RADIUS))
        ball.showturtle()

        balls.append(ball)

    draw(True)

    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT + 10)  # little bit added for title bar

bird = Turtle("circle", visible=False)
bird.shapesize(BIRD_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
bird.color("green")
bird.setheading(90)
bird.penup()
bird.showturtle()

balls = []
spare_balls = []

screen.tracer(False)

screen.onkey(click, "Up")
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

To make the turtle window the keyboard listener, you need to touch it with the mouse, to make it active, before hitting the up arrow key.

Before adding the current score to the window, you need to define how one scores.  (Is it the number of ball successfully dodged?)  Here I would use an additional, invisible turtle stationed in a fixed position that just does `undo()` and `write()` to update the scrore.